# Java recursion provides two different results. Why?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I have an ambiguous understanding about result of following code segment. Please help me to clearly understand this with an example.

This is my first code segment:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int number = 4;
    System.out.print(what(number));
}

public static int what(int number){
    if(number < 2)
        return 1;
    else
        return what(number-2) + what(number -1);
}
```

This returns 5 as the result. But when trying to run this recursion method individually for the operand both code segments return 1 as the result.

The following code returns 1 as the result:

```
public static int what(int number){
    if(number < 2)
        return 1;
    else
        return what(number-2);
}
```

and the same holds for this code:

```
public static int what(int number){
    if(number < 2)
        return 1;
    else
        return what(number-1);
}
```

I need to understand how this works.

Comment: The top and bottom methods are completely different in what they do. The bottom two will simply go through until they hit the condition and then return 1 while the top one will actually add up the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first method sums the 1's, whereas your latter method just print the result of `what()`, which can be nothing more or nothing less than 1.

Example of the first method:

> what(4) = what(2) + what(3) = what(0) + what(1) + what(1) + what(2) = 1 + 1 + 1 + what(0) + what(1) = 3 + 1 + 1 = 5

or, if you like a better visualization:

```
                   what(4)
                  /  +   \
                 /        \        
             what(2)      what(3)
            /   \         /     \
       what(0) what(1) what(1) what(2)
         =1     =1       =1     /  \
                            what(0) what(1)
                              =1      =1
```

Example of the second method:

> what(4) = what(2) = what(0) = 1

```
                     what(4)
                       |
                     what(2)
                       |
                     what(0)
                       =1
```

Example of the final method:

> what(4) = what(3) = what(2) = what(1) = 1

```
                     what(4)
                       |
                     what(3)
                       |
                     what(2)
                       |
                     what(1)
                       =1
```

Comment: The first method looks very Fibonacci to me (except for a 0 check, iirc).

Comment: Thanks for the better visualization. it made me clear. @vefthym

Answer (score 0):

When you are invoking `what(number-2) + what(number -1);` for every recursion 1 is added to existing result.

But when you are invoking them independently, you are simply overriding the previous calculations and returning 1.

Try to put a debug point and analyse how is the code running.

Answer (score 0):

For the recursive call to the method `what()` with argument 4 from main method, see the recursion tree -

```
                    4
                   / \
                  2   3
                     / \
                    1   2
```

Now you can see from the recursion tree how the method call  to `what()` occurred. Actually in the `what()` method the call is branched into two other call of `what()` if the argument to the method is greater that 2.